# PHP: List all files in a folder recursively and fast

Tags: php, recursion, scandir

I am looking for the fastest way to scan a directory recursively for all existing files and folders.

Example:

```
 - images
 -- image1.png
 -- image2.png
 -- thumbnails
 --- thumb1.png
 --- thumb2.png
 - documents
 -- test.pdf
```

Should return:

- images/image1.png
- images/image2.png
- images/thumbnails/thumb1.png
- images/thumbnails/thumb2.png
- documents/test.pdf

So I would start with:

```
$filesandfolders = @scandir( $path );
foreach ($filesandfolders as $f){
 if(is_dir($f)){
  //this is a folder
 } else {
 //this is a file 
}
}
```

But it this the fastest way?

Comment: Most of the time it's not the code that is slowest, but the storage hardware. In other words: There's not much to be gained from code that runs even faster than fast.

Comment: you may want to check this too http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: If tree command is available you can use it.

Comment: Disk access is always going to be the bottleneck in a task like this. If you can consider caching your results in memory then you will see a dramatic improvement.

Comment: Consider using [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` - but I doubt, it's faster than a simple recusive function.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/to/folder'));
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()) continue;
    $path = $file->getPathname();
}
```

Comment: It has to be. function calls are expensive in PHP.

Comment: @Sylwester behind the scenes, an iterator calls way more functions - rewind, valid, key, current, next - some of them for each iteration. But in this case, this shouldn't matter, because the bottleneck would be the disk

Answer (score 0):

I like this fancy output, any thoughts ?

```
function getAllContentOfLocation($loc)
{
    $scandir = scandir($loc);

    $scandir = array_filter($scandir, function ($element) {
        return !preg_match('/^\./', $element);
    });


    if (empty($scandir)) {
        echo '<p style="color:red">        Empty Dir</p>';
    }

    foreach ($scandir as $file) {
        $baseLink = $loc.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;

        echo '<ol>';
        if (is_dir($baseLink)) {
            echo '<p style="font-weight:bold;color:blue">'.$file.'</p>';
            getAllContentOfLocation($baseLink);
        } else {
            echo $file.'';
        }
        echo '</ol>';
    }
}
//Call function and set location that you want to scan
getAllContentOfLocation('.');
```